# Performance para múltiplos domínios em apenas um único servidor

Tags: apache, desempenho

Eu tenho 2 domínios apontados para um mesmo servidor(`Amazon EC2`) utilizando o `VirtualHost` do `Apache`.

Essa pratica interfere na performance e segurança ou o que vai influenciar será basicamente o número de acessos e recursos utilizados do servidor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Performance**

Apenas a quantidade de recursos interefere. O trabalho adicional que o Apache deverá realizar é desprezível na minha experiência. Nunca vi um benchmark realmente avaliando isto.

O que irá ocorrer, é que o Apache simplesmente terá que percorrer uma lista (ou outra estrutura qualquer) para identificar a qual vhost pertence a requisição, e então o processo continua normalmente.

**Segurança**

O site no vhost irá influenciar muito mais a segurança do que o feature vhost. Por exemplo, se o seu site hospedado em um vhost possuir uma rota que faz o download de um arquivo, e os parâmetros deste script não forem corretamente validados, pode ser que você consiga baixar um arquivo do outro site. Mas isto, como pode notar, não é uma falha da estrutura de vhost, e sim uma falha do seu site hospedado no vhost.

O único problema de se ter múltiplos vhosts em um mesmo servidor, é que o certificado digital deverá ser único para todos os sites, o que pode ser um problema. Esta limitação não se deve ao vhost, e sim ao fato que o handshake SSL/TLS ocorre antes da requisição HTTP ser enviada, e portanto não há como definir qual certificado utilizar: sempre o mesmo certificado é utilizado. Mas esta limitação não ocorre simplesmente pelo vhost, e sim pelo fato dos dois sites utilizarem o mesmo porto para conexão. Portanto, se você configurar cada vhost para trabalhar em um porto diferente, esta limitação será contornada.